# Evaluation metrics for chunking and synthesis steps for Q&A system

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, llm

I am doing research and interested in the following question:

**What are the evaluation metrics for chunking, retrieval and synthesis steps for Q&A, when I do NLQ with LLMs?** I am looking for scientific approach, not just human verification.

I am familiar with [this article](https://kaushikshakkari.medium.com/understanding-semantic-search-part-5-ranking-metrics-for-evaluating-question-answering-systems-f3150872d986) for retrieval, but cannot find anything on on metrics for evaluation of chunking and synthesis.

Basically, in a QnA system - when would you know you have achieved sufficient accuracy? How many questions would we need to see manually? And what brings this process to a stop?